# Put the value as title in text field

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

i want to get the partcular text value as tittle in that field
How can i do..

```
<input  type="text"
<?php if($name_one != '') { ?> value="<?php echo $name_one;?>" <?php echo set_value('name1'); ?> 
<?php } else { ?> value="<?php echo set_value('name1'); ?>" <?php } ?> 
 name="act1" id="act1" title="<?php echo set_value('name1'); ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
<input  type="text" 
value="<?php echo (!empty($name_one)) ? $name_one : $name1 ;  ?>"
```

Single line if condition